# Is it possible to install a 64-bit version of wine to run Photoshop CS5 x64?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, wine, photoshop

I'm trying to get a 64bit version of photoshop to work on Ubuntu 11.10. The problem is that Wine comes as 32 bit by default and I can only use the 32bit version of photoshop.  Is it possible to install Wine64 and have a 64 bit version of Photoshop working under linux?  Has anyone done this before that could give some insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build wine64 for your system (I'm unsure of a packaged version of it). Take a look at this link for info on building it.

http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine64

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, after CS3 they modify the MBR...so the answer from me is no.

Comment: What?, CS3 modifies the MBR? how?

Comment: During install one recent version of CS wrote copy protection to the back of the boot area.  It didn't interfere with the windows boot-loader, but it broke grub for some people.  Here's a link presenting both sides of the story: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t251090-photoshop-cs-on-dual-boot-linux-winxp-systems.html

Comment: Well, 2004 isn't what i'd call recent and they seem to be talking about CS not CS3 or 5, i do have CS5 installed and didn't brake anything must have been something they used back then.